# Ruby invoking attr method with array of attributes

Tags: ruby

Please explain me why i should define `attr_list` before `attr`? I can not understand why i should do that?

```
class Question
  def self.attr_list
    [:id, :name]
  end

  attr *self.attr_list
end
```

---

```
class Question
  attr *self.attr_list

  def self.attr_list
    [:id, :name]
  end
end
NoMethodError: undefined method `attr_list' for Question:Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a def, a class is executed line by line immediately after you hit return to run your program:

```
class Dog
  x = 10
  puts x
end

--output:--
10
```

...

```
class Dog
  puts x
  x=10
end

--output:--
1.rb:2:in `<class:Dog>': undefined local variable or method `x' 
  In this line:
```

...

```
class Dog
  def self.greet
    puts 'hello'
  end

  greet
end

--output:--
hello
```

...

```
class Dog
  greet

  def self.greet
    puts 'hello'
  end

end

--output:--
1.rb:2:in `<class:Dog>': undefined local variable or method `greet'
```

Similarly, in this line:

```
attr *self.attr_list
```

you call `self.attr_list()`, yet the def comes after that line, so the method doesn't exist yet.

With a def, you can write this:

```
def do_math()
  10/0
end
```

and you won't get an error until you call the method.

But by the time you create an instance of a class, all the code inside the class has already executed, creating the methods and constants that are defined inside the class.

By the way, you don't ever need to use `attr` because ruby 1.8.7+ has `attr_accessor`(reader and writer), `attr_reader`, and `attr_writer`.

Comment: Good answer. Also, don't forget that Ruby is an OO _scripting_ language. If you come from more structured languages like C or Java, you might expect the code to start with a `main` function; in Ruby, however, files are executed when they're loaded (they are scripts), and any root-level invocation (not a method body) is executed when it's parsed.